# Where is Apache Commons Email 1.6-SNAPSHOT?

Tags: maven, apache-commons-email

The project's homepage at (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/) has `1.6-SNAPSHOT` as the latest version, published on February 26 2018. Their dependency information page (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/dependency-info.html) also states that it should be available in Maven central. But when I tried using the exact dependency configuration they gave (`compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-email:1.6-SNAPSHOT'`), Gradle doesn't find the artifact. Searching the Maven Central repository gives 1.5 as the latest version: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-email. Even going to Apache Commons Email downloads page still only leads you to 1.5. I can't seem to find the source for 1.6 anywhere, and all searches only point to documentation for 1.6. Anyone know what's going on here? I'd understand if this was just released and it wasn't pushed to the repositories yet, but it's been months...

Comment: In Maven Central there will never be SNAPSHOT's...Apart from that https://mvnrepository ... is not Maven Central....This is the area where you need to look: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-email/  or via search engine: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ccommons-email Furthermore on the page given date is the last published date of the site and not of the artifact...

Comment: Oh I get it now, 1.6 is not released yet, hence the SNAPSHOT versions.

Comment: Although I'm still not clear why they would have 1.6-SNAPSHOT in the dependency info page then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version listed on the projects home page is not the version of the jars to download, but the version of the *homepage* (which is built by Maven).

You should use "the current release 1.5".